# Delphi7 CustomImageList problem

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, imagelist, tpngimagelist

I've run into the following problem:

My Delphi7 program runs smoothly on most computers running WinXP/Vista/7 BUT on some older Windows XP installs (only a few) I'm getting the following problem:

I have a system image list, and I'm adding my own icons to a copy of the system image list. Upon adding my icons I get an "Invalid image size." EInvalidOperation error.

Here is the code in question:

```
function GetSystemLargeIconsList: TCustomImageList;
// This gets the system image list.
var
  SysIL: HImageList;
  SFI: TSHFileInfo;
  MyImages: TCustomImageList;
begin
  SysIL := SHGetFileInfo('', 0, SFI, SizeOf(SFI),
     SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_LARGEICON);
  if SysIL <> 0 then begin
    MyImages:=TCustomImageList.Create(nil);
    // Assign the system list to the component
    MyImages.Handle := SysIL;
 // The following prevents the image list handle from being
 // destroyed when the component is.
    MyImages.ShareImages := TRUE;
    Result:=MyImages;
  end;
end;

var
    DocumentImgList: TCustomImageList;
    IconToAdd: TIcon;
begin
    DocumentImgList:=GetSystemLargeIconsList;

    Documents.LargeImages:=DocumentImgList;
    Documents.SmallImages:=DocumentImgList;

    IconToAdd:=TIcon.Create;

    DocumentListIcons.GetIcon(0, IconToAdd);
    DocumentImgList.AddIcon(IconToAdd); ----> this is the line of the exception
```

To make the problem worse, I'm using the TPngImageList component, but according to the code, it just seems to call the standard Delphi function:

```
if TObject(Self) is TPngImageList
then if Image = nil

...

else begin
     Patch := FindMethodPatch('AddIcon');
     if Patch <> nil
     then begin
          Patch.BeginInvokeOldMethod;
          try
            Result := TCustomImageList(Self).AddIcon(Image); ----> this is where the exception happens
          finally
            Patch.FinishInvokeOldMethod;
           end;
          end
     else Result := -1;
     end;
```

I've recently found out that on one of the computers that have this problem, either uxtheme.dll or explorer.exe has been patched with some Windows-skinning program.

So I suppose that somebody or a program is hacking the system image list in a way that is making my Delphi program crash.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could try would be to load your icon into a separate tBitmap, then resize it before adding it into the image list.

Comment: Problem is that I can't properly test it... My code relies heavily on the above (becuase it works on XP/Vista and 7) and even if I rewrite it there is no guarantee that it would work... I'm pretty sure that it's a Delphi7 issue! That's why I'm asking if anyone has seen something similar before...

Comment: If you can't test it, then how do you know what line the error is occurring at? Wrapping the GetIcon into a separate function doesn't seem like a risky solution, since you should be able to verify the correct behavior with a machine that doesn't experience the problem.  Then test it on one that does.

Comment: I'm using EurekaLog to trace bugs - it is giving me back the line number. Can you give some example code for your solution? Will this properly work with icons which have a transparent background?